# required property of input field not working and input field color does not changed

Tags: html, css, angular

```
   <div class="container">
      <h1>SignUp Form</h1>
        <form>
        <div class="form-group" >
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'red-border':user.name.errors}" [(ngModel)]="user.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="name" required >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control"   id="pass"  [(ngModel)]="user.pass" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="cpass">Confirm Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control"  id="cpass "required [(ngModel)]="user.cpass" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">DOB</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" required [(ngModel)]="user.dob"[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required [(ngModel)]="user.email" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact">Contact</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" required [(ngModel)]="user.contact" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </div>
        <button type="button"  (click)="validateUser(user)" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

I am new to angular 2, i had tried required property in input tag,but its not working. Also i want to change the color when input in wrong. I tried it but i don,t get it how to do it. Here is the code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tevhas

Answer (score 0):

give name to your input field like `name="name"` and then try this `user.name.errors.required` instead of `user.name.errors`

Comment: error occurred:can not read property 'required ' of undefined.

Comment: Also can you suggest how to change color of input field if input validation failed